Intermittent DNS Failures in Azure Function
I have a Node.js timer function (Node.js v18, Linux, Consumption) running at Azure that is failing intermittently, citing what appears to be DNS lookup failures. The function runs every 30 minutes. It will work for several days just fine, and then start failing for 12-24 hours, and then start working again.
Here is the error from the logs. This error occurs when the @hubspot/api-client library sends a request to the HubSpot API. This is a public API with a host of api.hubapi.com.
Exception: request to https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/products?limit=100&after=2663219990&properties=hs_lastmodifieddate%2Chs_sku%2Chs_images&archived=false failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN api.hubapi.com
Here are a few things I have tried, based on my research:

Updated the @hubspot/api-client dependency to latest version, in case there was an issue with the library.
In the Function App, I changed the Outbound DNS to Custom, listing Cloudflare (1.1.1.1) and Quad9 (9.9.9.9) instead of the default Azure DNS, in case there was an issue with the Azure DNS.

Those two changes didn't help resolve the issue. This function works well locally, as well as on GCP, where it was deployed previously.

What is Hubspot API? Is this your Azure Function API Name? Can you provide some code of it or functionality details?

@JashuaCriss Hubspot is a CRM provider with a public API. The function could just be sending a GET request to google.com from Node and failing. I think it's the same thing because it is DNS related.

just some thoughts:
Running any http request from Azure function in consumption plan can yield to these kind of exceptions (in .net):
•   No such host is known
•   The request was canceled
•   The remote name could not be resolved
•   A complete response was not received from the remote server
•   A complete request could not be sent to the remote server
•   The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found
•   A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
These usually stem from the fact you are running without a vNet and using some sort of a shared or public DNS server. In contrast, SDK operations against other Azure services (PAAS,IAAS, etc) have embedded retries, so that you don´t officially experience these errors. So, overall if your Azure Functions in consumption must connect with an http client to any other service you must make sure these connections have retries.

Thanks for this. I moved my function app from a Consumption (Y1) plan to a Premium (EP1) plan. This seems to have resolved the issue, finally. I'd still be interested to know why requests to Azure's (or public i.e. Cloudflare's) DNS servers are failing so consistently for up to to 24 hours. But I guess the simple answer is just to pay Azure more to make the error go away. ;)

Great to hear you got it working. I wrote a whole rant on Azure Functions and AWS Lambdas here: https://medium.com/@bajani2007/to-be-serverless-or-not-fef4590c79c3 - have a look, you may find other interesting gotchas. Cheers

It's worse than you that... our primary issue is Failed to resolve 'graph.microsoft.com' ([Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution, i.e, our Azure function is not even able to resolve the MS Graph API endpoint.  And as with others, this is intermittent so fixing this continues to elude us.
